# Why does Rect.contains(right,bottom) returns false?

Tags: android, rect

I am debugging a problem with my touchcode and I stumbled upon this weird behaviour of the `Rect` class.

```
Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,10,10);
rect.contains(0,0)   // true
rect.contains(10,10) // false
rect.contains(9,9)   // true
```

Why is this happening??!

Why are the right and bottom bounds exclusive and the left and top inclusive? I don't find it logical, and there is no documentation that notes this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected/documented. From [the `contains(int, int)` reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#contains%28int,%20int%29):

> The left and top are considered to be inside, **while the right and bottom are not.** This means that for a x,y to be contained: left <= x < right and top <= y < bottom.

Although I agree this seems a little illogical, it makes more sense when you consider an edge case:

> An empty rectangle never contains any point.

This behavior also prevents a single `x,y` point from being contained within multiple, non-intersecting `Rect`s.

Comment: Ok, that explanation makes a lot of sense!